# Querying items with values inside an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

Let's say I have many records in my database similar to this one

```
{
  "basename": "2020bb",
  "entries": [
    {
      "name": "030-c1.bin",
      "extension": "bin",
      "basename": "030-c1",
      "crc": "4f5e19bd",
      "size": 1048576
    },
    {
      "name": "030-c2.bin",
      "extension": "bin",
      "basename": "030-c2",
      "crc": "d6314bf0",
      "size": 1048576
    },
    {
      "name": "030-c3.bin",
      "extension": "bin",
      "basename": "030-c3",
      "crc": "47fddfee",
      "size": 1048576
    }
  ]
}
```

they all have that structure, but different `basename`s different `entries`

Now I have a list of `basename`s and `crc`s of `entries` that I want to find records for. Like so:

```
{
  "basename": {
    "$in": [
      "2020bb",
      "alpham2p"
    ]
  },
  "entries": {
    "$in": [
      [
        { "$elemMatch": { "crc": "4f5e19bd" } },
        { "$elemMatch": { "crc": "d6314bf0" } },
        { "$elemMatch": { "crc": "47fddfee" } }
      ],
      [
        { "$elemMatch": { "crc": "c763e52a" } },
        { "$elemMatch": { "crc": "7a0b435c" } },
        { "$elemMatch": { "crc": "efc9ae2e" } }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

With this query I am trying to find the items that have

- the `basename` `2020bb` and `entries` with the `crc` values `4f5e19bd, d6314bf0, 47fddfee`
- the `basename` `alpham2p` and the `entries` with the `crc` values `c763e52a, 7a0b435c, efc9ae2e`

I hope my intention is clear. Sadly this just gives me 0 results.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the query statement you are using?

Comment: The second codeblock actually is the query statement, it's just stripped as there are a lot more `basename`s and `entries` I am querying for

Comment: For the `crc` values, do all 3 of the listed values need to be present in `entries`, or just  one of them?

Answer (score -1):

```
db.collection.find({
    basename: {
        "$in": ["2020bb", "alpham2p"]
    },
    entries: {
        $elemMatch: {
            crc: {
                $in: ["4f5e19bd", "d6314bf0", "47fddfee", "c763e52a", "7a0b435c", "efc9ae2e"]
            }
        }
    }
})
```